# Background image changer interval Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, intervals, interactive

I'm new to javascript and I need some help with a function that I am trying to get to run. I would like for the background of my body to change every  seconds using the images provided but when I try to run the script it does not seem to work.

Javascript:

```
var i = 0;
var images = [
URL('file:///Users/BodyDesigns/Documents/Altered%20Images/P1010216.jpg'),
URL('file:///Users/BodyDesigns/Documents/Altered%20Images/P1010217.jpg'),
URL('file:///Users/BodyDesigns/Documents/Altered%20Images/P1010200.jpg')
];

function backgroundChanger() {
for(; i < images.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('background').style.backgroundImage.innerHTML = images[i];
}
}

setInterval( backgroundChanger(), 4000);
```

html:

```
<body id="background" onLoad="backgroundChanger()">
```

Comment: Typo in `for(; i < images.length; i++)` and remove the parenthesis in `setInterval( backgroundChanger(), 4000);`. Also, your for loop will run through all the images quickly which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
var i = 0;
var images = [
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Screenshot_from_IMAX%C2%AE_3D_movie_Hidden_Universe_showing_the_Helix_Nebula_in_infrared.jpg',
    'http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/wwfeatures/wm/live/1280_640/images/live/p0/40/m0/p040m0bc.jpg',
    'http://az616578.vo.msecnd.net/files/2016/08/06/636060577940287734-194579614_maxresdefault.jpg'
];

function backgroundChanger() {
  if(i >= images.length){
    i = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById('background').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[i++] + ')';
}

setInterval( backgroundChanger, 4000);
```

As you can see, the `url()` should be passed inside a string to work. And there is no innerHtml on `backgroundImage` property.